# show database data according to previous database selection

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am trying to get data of events out of my database and show it on my homepage.
My **database table**:

```
TABLE `events` (
    `event_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_desc` TEXT,
    `event_location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_requirements` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
```

My **code** (in a MVC architecture):
Controller

```
function index()
    {
        $overview_model = $this->loadModel('Events');
        $this->view->events = $overview_model->getEventTypes();
        $this->view->render('events/index');
    }
```

Model

```
public function getEventTypes()
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events");
        $sth->execute();

        $events = array();

        foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $event) {
            $events[$event->event_id] = new stdClass();
            $events[$event->event_id]->event_title = $event->event_title;
            $events[$event->event_id]->event_desc = $event->event_desc;
            $events[$event->event_id]->event_location = $event->event_location;
            $events[$event->event_id]->event_requirements = $event->event_requirements;
            $events[$event->event_id]->event_date = $event->event_date;
        }
        return $events;
    }
```

View

```
        <!-------- WORKS --------------->
        <!-- start event type selection --> 
        <div class="event-selection">
           <label>Choose an event:</label>
           <select id="select-event-type">
              <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
                echo "<option value='" .$event->event_title. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
            }?>
        </select>
        </div><!-- /.event-selection -->

        <!-------- DOES NOT WORK --------------->
        <!-- Start option 1 -->
        <div id="option1" class="group">
            <h2><?php $event->event_title ?></h2>
            <p><?php $event->event_desc ?></p>
            <p><?php $event->event_location ?></p>
            <p><?php $event->event_requirements ?></p>
            <p><?php $event->event_date ?></p>
        </div> <!-- /#option 1 -->              
    </div><!-- /.event-selection -->
```

**What I am trying to achieve**, is to have a drop down menu, from which the user can select an event (that part works!). And then display the information of that event below the drop down menu (that part does not work!).
I do not get any error messages. My outcome in the browser is nothing and in the console is this:

```
<!-- Start option 1 -->
<div id="option1" class="group">
     <h2></h2>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
</div> <!-- /#option 1 -->
```

I am really new to this and I would highly appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<?php $event->event_title ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $event->event_title; ?>
```

You are not `echoing` the result.You have used `PHP` in `HTML` so you have to echo the result.And for your select box to select the DB result you have to check like

```
<select id="select-event-type">
          <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {

            if($event->event_title == $db_event_title) {
                 echo "<option value='" .$event->event_title. "' selected='selected'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
            } else {
                 echo "<option value='" .$event->event_title. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
            }
        }?>
</select>
```

Comment: However, it still is not updating the data, when I change the selected event in the drop down menu. It is just showing the first entry all the time.

Comment: For that you have to check the options with the DB result